# My Ubuntu 18.04 not booting in anymore

Tags: ubuntu

A few days ago my OS was working fine. Then a next day it just stuck with a lots of progress lines.

The final line is:

[Ok] Started session c6 of user gdm. [Ok] Started user manager for UID 121

Comment: This has already been [answered here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163516/problems-with-booting-the-system)